# Better way to parse CSV into list or array

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, numpy

Is there a better way to create a list or a numpy array from this [csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BwmIoMM4eZGdedTaWrK6WSMhwdo4f1o3/view?usp=sharing)?  What I'm asking is how to do it and parse more gracefully than I did in the code below.

```
fname = open("Computers discovered recently by discovery method.csv").readlines()
lst = [elt.strip().split(",")[8:] for elt in fname if elt != "\n"][4:]

lst2 = []
for row in lst:
    print(row)
    if row[0].startswith("SMZ-") or row[0].startswith("MTR-"):
        lst2.append(row)

print(*lst2, sep = "\n")
```

Comment: How about pandas dataframe?

Comment: @Garbage I haven't learned them yet. Examples are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never parse CSV structures manually unless you want to tackle all possible exceptions and CSV format oddities. Python has you covered in that regard with its `csv` module.

The main problem, in your case, stems from your data - there seems to be two different CSV structures in a single file so you first need to find where your second structure begins. Plus, from your code, it seems you want to filter out all columns before `Details_Table0_Netbios_Name0` and include only rows whose `Details_Table0_Netbios_Name0` starts with `SMZ-` or `MTR-`. So something like:

```
import csv

with open("Computers discovered recently by discovery method.csv") as f: 
    reader = csv.reader(f)  # create a CSV reader
    for row in reader:  # skip the lines until we encounter the second CSV structure/header
        if row and row[0] == "Header_Table0_Netbios_Name0":
            break
    index = row.index("Details_Table0_Netbios_Name0")  # find where your columns begin
    result = []  # storage for the rows we're interested in
    for row in reader:  # read the rest of the CSV row by row
        if row and row[index][:4] in {"SMZ-", "MTR-"}:  # only include these rows
            result.append(row[index:])  # trim and append to the `result` list

print(result[10])  # etc.
# ['MTR-PC0BXQE6-LB', 'PR2', 'anisita', 'VALUEADDCO', 'VALUEADDCO', 'Heartbeat Discovery',
#  '07.12.2017 17:47:51', '13']
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! Also, comments are very helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can always use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org). As an example,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('pandas_dataframe_importing_csv/example.csv')
```

To convert it, you will have to convert it to your favorite numeric type. I guess you can write the whole thing in one line:

```
result = numpy.array(list(df)).astype("float")
```

You can also do the following:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('my_file.csv', delimiter=',')
```

Comment: to get the corresponding numpy array just do `result = df.values`

Comment: True, I added `astype()` In case he wants to do some edits.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want but try this

```
import csv
with open("Computers discovered recently by discovery method.csv", 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    ll = list(reader)

print (ll)
```

this should read the csv line by line and store it as a list

Comment: Thanks for the try :D There is a link to csv file in my first post. You can download and try your code on it. (spoiler alert: it won't work)

Comment: @user2978216 Using the csv library is a better way than parsing the csv file yourself. The csv library supports common dialects as well as customized dialects if you need it too. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: @user2978216 delete the first 3 lines of the csv and run it it'll work

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas and specify header column to make it work correctly on you sample file

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Computers discovered recently by discovery method.csv', header=2)
```

You can check your content using:

```
>>> df.head()
```

You can check headers using

```
>>> df.columns
```

And to convert it to `numpy` array you can use

```
>>> np_arr = df.values
```

It comes with a lot of options to parse and read csv files. For more information please check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Sample Code**

```
import csv
csv_file = 'sample.csv'
with open(csv_file) as fh:
  reader = csv.reader(fh)
  for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

**sample.csv**

```
name,age,salary
clado,20,25000
student,30,34000
sam,34,32000
```